Nested custom commands not working
I have defined the following commands for my latex document:
\newcommand{\uat}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\boldsymbol{u}_{#1}}{\boldsymbol{u}_{#1}(#2)}}
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\textnormal{opt}}{#1^*}}

The commands work fine separately. The first defined a variable with has optionally a index (first argument) and braces with the time (second argument). The second command defines two ways of denoting a variable is optimal. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\uat}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{\boldsymbol{u}_{#1}}{\boldsymbol{u}_{#1}(#2)}}
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\textnormal{opt}}{#1^*}}

\begin{document}

$\uat{}{t}$
$\opt{u(t)}$

% $\opt{\uat{}{t}}$  % does not work

\end{document}

However, when I do
\opt{\uat{}{}}

several errors appear.
Does someone have an idea how to solve that?
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a full minimal working example which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Anyway, AFAIR \ifthenelse cannot be nested, at least not in the test argument.

Thanks for the comment, I provided a minimal example!

the \ifthenelse \equal test tests if the two arguments are equal after expansion but commands defined using \ifthenelse are (as documented) not expandable.

use \IfBlankTF{#1}{yes}{no}  which is an expandable test that does not require any package

EDIT David reminded me that \IfBlank(TF) is part of the kernel now...
\ifthenelse cannot be nested in the test argument. You need another test for empty argument: I guess there's at least a half-dozen solutions, but with a recent kernel you can use the built-in \IfBlank(TF), which is expandable and can be nested.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% not sure how useful this \uat is...
\newcommand*{\uat}[2]{\boldsymbol{u}\IfBlankF{#1}{_{#1}}\IfBlankF{#2}{(#2)}}
\newcommand*{\opt}[1]{\IfBlankTF{#1}{\textnormal{opt}}{#1^*}}

\begin{document}

$\uat{}{t}$\par
$\opt{u(t)}$\par
$\opt{}$\par
$\opt{\uat{}{t}}$

\end{document}


Note the test also for the first argument of \uat. Without it, an empty first argument would lead to $u_{}(...)$, which introduces some horizontal space.

My personal preference actually goes to \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#1?}\relax, but it's longer to type :-)

which is \IfBlankTF, more or less.

@DavidCarlisle Ah, I obviously missed that being in the kernel now...

@DavidCarlisle where can I find a documentation of the functions IfBlankTF{} and similars? Does there exist such a documentation?

@Trb2 It's escribed in the current user guide, texdoc usrguide.
